# Sed command is not working as expected in the inner directory files

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I wanted to delete and replace the first three lines of files in a directory that met a certain condition.  I used the following code:

```
test=find . -name "*.java"
testing $test

function testing{
    for var in $@
    do
        echo $var
        if head -3 $var | grep '^ \*$';then
            echo "in if"
            sed '1,3d' $var > tmp.java; mv tmp.java $var
            echo -e "/**\n* new text\n**/" | cat - $var > temp.java
    done
}
```

The code works fine for the current directory files but fails for child directory files.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I've edited your post for proper markdown, and if you claim that this worked for *anything*, you must have missed a few things when copying. Copy paste your code into the editor, select the whole code block and then use Ctrl-K or select the curly braces from the editor menu.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is hard to read, but to replace the first lines of code you could use the sed command like this

```
sed -i '1,3s/.*/REPLACE_TEXT/' JAVA_FILE
```

Your script should look like this

```
test=$(find . -name "*.java")
testing $test

function testing{
    for var in $@
    do
        echo $var
        if head -3 $var | grep '^ \*$';then
            echo "in if"
            sed -i '1,3s/.*/REPLACE_TEXT/' $var
        fi
    done
}
```